# How to obfuscate symbol names with a password in confuserex?

Tags: c#, .net, passwords, obfuscation, confuserex

For example, in Eazfuscator.Net you can obfuscate the symbol names with

```
[assembly: Obfuscation(Feature = "encrypt symbol names with password XPASSWORD", Exclude = false)]
```

but I was wondering how you can do that (doesn't matter if it includes code or the app gui itself) with ConfuserEx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the ConfuserEx Wiki [Name Protection](https://github.com/mkaring/ConfuserEx/wiki/Name-Protection)

Example:

```
<protection id="rename">
  <argument name="mode" value="reversible" />
  <argument name="password" value="This password is secret" />
  <argument name="renameArgs" value="true" />
  <argument name="renEnum" value="true" />
  <argument name="flatten" value="true" />
  <argument name="forceRen" value="false" />
  <argument name="renPublic" value="false" />
  <argument name="renPdb" value="true" />
  <argument name="renXaml" value="true" />
</protection>
```

The important parts are `mode` as `reversible` and `password` don't need explanation. All this in the .crproj file.

But if you want to use direct obfuscation declaration in class then use [Declarative Obfuscation](https://github.com/mkaring/ConfuserEx/wiki/Declarative-Obfuscation)